# Troubles streaming NetFlix to PS3 through router

Tags: router, home-networking, streaming, netflix

I just downloaded and installed the new NetFlix application for the PS3, but it turns out my router is blocking it for some reason.  If I connect the PS3 directly to the cable modem, NetFlix works fine.

I have a D-Link 4 port router (DI-604), any ideas on how to get the router to stop blocking NetFlix?

Online game play, internet, and PSN access all work fine.  Also the NetFlix disc used to work, the problem only started when I had to switch to the application.

Edit:

Talked to NetFlix again, no help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to D-Link EBR-2310 router.  Now everything is working fine.